# Admins do not have the ability to edit the deployment permissions, only Owner does

Tags: deployment, admin, google-app-maker

I have 3 other members who are listed in the admin role. They have the ability to make edits in the UI for the application; however, when it comes to edit the deployment such as granting users access to the deployment, they do not have the option for edit. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

That is an expected behavior. Although there is nothing found in the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/deployment) that explains this, there is a thread in the [appmaker google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/appmaker-users/edit$20deployment%7Csort:date/appmaker-users/_c5powOVwG8/yDObY2u4BAAJ) that explains this is not possible and apparently, it is a feature the appmaker engineers are planning to integrate in the future.